# Magento Reviews Disappearing from Database

Tags: database, security

We have a strange issue occurring where product reviews are mysteriously disappearing from the Magento database. They are there one day and then the next we check the database and they are completely gone. Like they have been deleted. We've lost entire months of data at a time.

We are at somewhat of a loss at how/why this could be happening. We have not installed any extensions that are related to reviews.

At this point we are starting to thing there may be some sort of a site hack that is causing this issue.

Wondering if anyone else has seen this problem or any ideas as to what may be causing the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you contact your hosting company? Is it possible that they have reverted the database to a previous version or having other server syncing issues? Also are you only having issue with reviews

Comment: Are you keeping your incremental backups and then comparing?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like some sort of exploit has been found in your frontend code that is being used to manipulate the database.

You should be able to review your servers access logs to see any such activity and or enable MySQL slowlog to log all queries being run and see if there is any delete or truncate commands being run.

Stuart

Comment: I just read your answer after posting mine.

Comment: I don't think mysql slow query log will catch the query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your site is hacked, it could be something hosting/server side. I would suggest to check if you have any CRON enabled which deletes it everyday. Or as @R.S said check with your hosting provider may be some glitch in backup process.

I would also enable mysql queries log to check at what time it's deleting all the reviews and what queries were being run. Stay chill, your site is not hacked as there are other more sensitive data in DB than just product reviews :)